# Publish C# application with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, setup-deployment, oneclick

My application does basic CRUD operations over an external `.mdf` file. The database file is created separately in SSMS. On my PC, everything works perfectly fine. When I install it on someone else's computer, it refuses to connect to the database. The other PC also has the same database at the exact same location.

The connection string I am using is (in `app.config`):

```
conString=Data Source =.\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog = dbName;
Integrated Security = True; Pooling = False
```

In my code:

```
dbConnection = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.conString);
```

The other PC has SQL Server installed as well. Tried going through almost all the results but almost all of them suggest either

1. Adding the existing database with the project. I can't seem to do that because when I try that I get an error:

   > permission denied
2. I can't rewrite the whole code with a service based database pre-attached to it.

Comment: hi have you check the name of the sql server ma y me he installed with fiffrent name . please connect o ssms of the other machine and chage connection string

Comment: Try catching the exception when connecting to figure out what fails (db not found, authentication problem etc.)

Comment: Find the local instance dynamically, sometime it differs based on instance name chosen during installation. You can use this link to know local instance of SQL Server
**SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms210334.aspx

Comment: You should use SQL Server Compact Edition as this doesn't require you to install anything on the computer you wish to run your program on, you simply bundle the SQLCE dll's with your program as a normal assembly that you have referenced. Most likely this requires you to create the database file again though.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot open database 'dbName' requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed foir user 'Desktop-XYZ'.

Comment: Solved the problem. Turns out all i needed to do was open SSMS on the other computer and attach the copied database. Thank you all for leading me on the right track.